# Renamed table in mysql makes error in every Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I renamed one of my table in my database "igp".

**domain** to **projects**

While I am running the query
 `INSERT INTO projects (title,disease_area_id) VALUES ('ghf', 1)` 
It makes an error
Error : `#1146 - Table 'igp.domain' doesn't exist`

Comment: of course!! you have to make changes where `domain` table name is used

Comment: currently I am not using domain table.

Comment: show the result of mysql> show tables;  command

Comment: what is database engine type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check any triggers pointing to domain table on Insert operation